# Excel 2013: Sorting and Linking data to master tabel

Tags: excel, sorting

It appears my database skills are woefully out of date and I need some help.

How do I link tables together in Excel so the related tables will sort with the master table?

Example:

1. Master Table: Part Number (Primary Key),  Description, Mfg. Priority
2. Related Table 1: Part Number (Linked Primary Key), Size, Color, etc.
3. Related Table 2: Part Number (Linked Primary Key), Raw Material 1....2

When the sort order is changed in the Master Table, I need the sort order and all the corresponding data to change in the related tables.

Thanks, OnPoint